# Is rethrowing exceptions good practice?

Tags: c#, exception

do you think catching an Exception and rethrowing it is a good practice?

Basically I have a piece of code, where a color is created using its constructor with 3 params. And the color constructor may throw an exception.

```
    public PointExtend(double x, double y, int r, int g, int b)
        : base(x, y)
    {
        try
        {
            var color = new Color(r, g, b);
            Color = color;                
        }
        catch (InvalidColorValueException)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Resharper says, the catch-throw clause is redundant, I agree, considering I don't do anything with the Exception but throw it again and had I not, it would leak to UI anyway, but isn't this code for a programmer easier to read, so that if he creates PointExtend he will know, what the code may throw?

Comment: I thin it is pointless unless you are throwing a customized exception

Comment: The `catch/throw` *is* redundant. It's equivalent to having no catch at all. This isn't cleaner code, it's an unexpected surprise and head-scratching trying to understand what the author meant and whether something is missing from the code

Comment: What do you mean by good practice? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Petar mentioned Comments, npinti mentioned the ///summary above function, which I completely forgot about. I think their Ideas are actually valid and will choose my own way from now own, instead of rethrowing the exception.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd I was trying to achieve a code easier to read by a programmer. A programmer sees, this PointExtend constructor may throw an exception, so if he wants to use the PointExtend constructort somewhere else, he will have to catch the InvalidColorValueException which may be thrown. But I now see doing it this way is not the best idea and using comments or ///summary is much more welcome.

Answer (score 2):

You are really getting bad advice here from people trying to convince you that you should document your code.

Only poorly written code needs comments, instead of taking the effort to write comment, good comment, spend that effort in your code so that it does not need comment at all.

Does that mean that all comment is evil. No of course not. There are cases when comment is still needed because the programming languages are not always best suited to describe what is going on very well. But even then care must be taken because the comment will start to live a life of its own.

http://apdevblog.com/comments-in-code/

is a blog referring to *Clean Code by Robert C. Martin*

There is a whole chapter in that book about comments, those who think you need comment better read that book.

In your particular case if you really feel like the code is better when you catch the exception and then rethrow it without extra, by all means leave it in.
Personally I would leave it out. But to me this is just a style issue. Make an agreement with your fellow workers and be consistent in your team.

My answer here can cause quite a debate, you are all free to your own opinion on the subject. (Robert Martin says the same thing ;-)) But the truth of the matter is that in many cases the comment just clutters the code and reduces readability. Comment is forgotten to be updated and hence is no longer inline with the real code, ...

An alternative to documenting everything is to write good unit tests. By reading the code of the unit tests, if they are written well, you will get the hang on how the code is supposed to be used. That is if you are writing an api to be used by other people.

Well written code which is also well layered does not need to be crunched up to every single class in the system. If you have to do this in order to understand the code then the conclusion is yet again the same. It is bad code.

Method names, and variable names, class names go very far. After reading the book of clean code, I have changed my style of code considerably.

I am writing software for 20 years now and I have seen, and written a lot of comment. In many cases it is still not clear what they really mean in that comment or the comment is just blatently wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the time you put into this reply, Philip. So you in fact think I should remove the try catch clause and then another programmer, would someone work on my code, should just figure on his own, that the Color constructor may in fact throw an exception, meaning he has to open the Color class as well, rather than seeing it directly in the PointExtend class? I am not a fan of comments, either, I try to write understandable code, but so far we were working mostly in C++, crafting algorithms, and were introduced to the whole Exception concept only recently.

Comment: That is the position I would take in a team meeting, to remove the try catch. But if the team decides differently I would follow up on the team's decision. Sw is not always black and white when it comes to design.

Comment: Sadly, but rightly so, it's almost *never* about what you would want individually as a purist (e.g. code needs to comment itself. Period.), it's about what the people in your team, the surrounding teams and the organization have agreed on or think is a good idea. You're just gonna be 'that one guy' in most orgs.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are doing any particular logging or exception wrapping, you can remove it.

If you want the programmer to *know* about the possible exception, document it:

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates a new instance of <code>PointExtend</code>
/// </summary>
/// <param name="x">...</param>
/// <param name="y">...</param>
/// <param name="r">...</param>
/// <param name="g">...</param>
/// <param name="b">...</param>
/// <exception cref="InvalidColorValueException">Should the provided rgb values be out of range</exception>
public PointExtend(double x, double y, int r, int g, int b)
        : base(x, y)
    {            
            var color = new Color(r, g, b);
            Color = color;                            
    }
```

This will allow other programmers which consume your API to know what the constructor does and any potential pitfalls. Not everyone might have access to your code.

EDIT: As per @Philip Stuyck's comment, although I do agree, it is also my opinion that we do not live in an ideal world. The problem with what you are recommending is that:

- What would happen if you are required to ship an obfuscated version of your DLL? This is what usually happens when companies sell their DLL's. You cannot really look into the code, and method names can only go so far.
- Most projects tend to be more than a mere handful of classes, and going through code each time to figure out what is going on can be time consuming and can put people off from using your product. Open Source projects are, in my opinion a clear example of [this](http://ostatic.com/blog/its-2014-and-open-source-documentation-is-still-lacking).
- Lastly, and more importantly, in my opinion, the only section where you say what your code does is in the *summary* section (in the case for .NET at least). Comments and documentation should shed light on *why* was a given approach chosen.

Comment: This is actually neat, I completely forgot about the ///summary ability C# provides, thank you.

Comment: @OndřejŠimon: In an ideal world, code *should* be documented because you never know who/from where someone else will be working on.

Comment: These are all my projects, for school, but I suppose you should learn to program well on your small projects, so when working on something large, other programmers won't have problems reading your code.

Comment: @OndřejŠimon: Larger projects are usually a collection of smaller projects. Also, it is best you learn good practices while you are starting, since it would be more difficult to change bad habits once you get the hang of them.

Comment: In an ideal world code does not need documentation or comment. Only badly written code needs comment.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck: I do not agree with what you are saying, for the simple reason we do not live in an ideal world. I have tried to come up with some reasons about this in the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

The throw in the code above is pointless as you say,  all the runtime will do is just re throw the same exception. You can remove the try catch and it would function the same.

If you did something with the exception itself that's the reason to catch it, otherwise let it bubble up and give the user a meaningful message, log it in an error log and you, and the user is not just given a nonsense exception pop up :)

Answer (score -2):

If you want the programmer to know something use comments.
Catching and throwing exceptions is an overhead and is useless (except if you do something with it before re-throw, i.e. log it), so the programmer will actually be confused, thinking there is a bug and not understanding what the original intent was.

Comment: npinti mentioned the ///summary, I think I will use that from now on. Thanks for the reply nonetheless. I appreciate it, Petar.

Comment: code that needs comment is bad code. rewrite the code so that it documents itself.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck How exactly should I rewrite this specific part of code, a part, where an object, which is created, may throw an Exception? I think some documentation is necessary, in this case.

Comment: you leave it as it is or you follow the suggestion of resharper to remove the unneeded code. But you don't add comment, because comment can go out of context and will go out of context from the rest of the code.